# Fetching Tuple from python code with Python.NET library

Tags: python, c#, python.net

I use Python.Net library to run python code from c# environment.

My python function returns 4 integers in that way :
`return num1, num2, num3, num4`
I have problem with fetching this data from c# code. Result goes as PyObject and i cannot convert it to any other type to get the response values.

Comment: Can you modify the return type to be an array instead?

Comment: It hard to me to get access to python code ... i can modify it localy but its a long way to provide changes globaly :(

Comment: Can you post the C# code where you try to access the result of python call?

Comment: My trying was simple : 
`using (Py.GIL())
 {
     pyModule = Py.Import("someModule");
     var res = pyModule.doSomethingInPython();
     List<int> res = pyModule.doSomethingInPython();
     Tuple<object, object, object, object> res = pyModule.doSomethingInPython();
     Tuple<int, int, int, int> res = pyModule.doSomethingInPython();
}`

Comment: get the result in `object res = ...` and check in the debugger what comes from python.net